# Equations from graphs

Tags: graphing-functions

Could anyone help me to write the equations of these two functions:
[image]

I'm trying to replicate the graphs in R, but don't know what the functions are

Comment: notice that the y-axis is scaled logarithmically.

Comment: Yes, I did notice it. I suppose I'll have something like:
y = exp (x...)

Comment: a linear plot on a loglinscale (y-axis) is of the form $y=ab^x$. Can you find two points, substitute their values for $x$ and $y$ and solve the system of equations for $a$ and $b$?